# Does von Neumann say anything about which way data flows?

Tags: reactjs, dataflow, von-neumann

I stumbled upon this quote while reading about React (emphasis mine)

> In React, data flows one way: from owner to child. This is because **data only flows one direction in the Von Neumann model of computing**.

[React Docs: Two-Way Binding Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html)

It links to the [Wikipedia article about the Von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) but I think Wikipedia and some other sources don't say anything about data flow in regards to von Neumann architectures and/or models of computing. Dataflow architecture (no link because my reputation is below 10) gets mentioned here and there but it seems to be an **alternative** to von Neumann architectures.

I'm not so much interested in the React side of this, but more in the theory part which I did not find any material about.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html

Comment: @HansPassant I'll assume this means it's wrong, nothing to do with the actual von Neumann architecture.

Comment: I guess React document should update this inside their doc or provide some another link which talks more about data flow #reactjs